# pyparsing - Parsing a function call to get function name and argument list

Tags: function, parsing, arguments, pyparsing

I have some complicated function calls which i want to parse to get function name and argument list. examples of the function calls are below:

1) extend(lambda x: 'xxxx' if t='xx' else t.replace('a','').replace('b',''), ['col_name1'], 'col_name', 'string')

2) restrict(lambda x:x !=0, ['col'])

I have tried to parse this using regex but so far it fails to parse the argument list properly. i am new to pyparsing so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are some pretty complicated argument lists in those functions. So if you are trying to parse *them*, this will be a pretty big job.

However, if you just want the function name, and a string of the arguments passed in, then with pyparsing, you can use some easy short-cuts.

If you keep your plan very high-level, you can write your BNF as:

```
function_call ::= identifier '(' arguments ')'
idenntifier ::= word starting with alpha or '_', followed by zero or more alphanums or '_'
arguments ::= (let's not worry about this for the moment)
```

If we just consider the arguments as a list of items that may be nested in one or more levels of parentheses, then we can use pyparsing's `nestedExpr` helper to capture them.

```
import pyparsing as pp

identifier = pp.Word('_' + pp.alphas, '_' + pp.alphanums)
arg_list = pp.nestedExpr()  # nesting delimiters default to '(' and ')'
function_call = identifier("name") + arg_list("args")

tests = """\
    extend(lambda x: 'xxxx' if t='xx' else t.replace('a','').replace('b',''), ['col_name1'], 'col_name', 'string')
    restrict(lambda x:x !=0, ['col'])"""

function_call.runTests(tests)
```

Prints:

```
extend(lambda x: 'xxxx' if t='xx' else t.replace('a','').replace('b',''), ['col_name1'], 'col_name', 'string')
['extend', ['lambda', 'x:', "'xxxx'", 'if', 't=', "'xx'", 'else', 't.replace', ["'a'", ',', "''"], '.replace', ["'b'", ',', "''"], ',', '[', "'col_name1'", '],', "'col_name'", ',', "'string'"]]
- args: [['lambda', 'x:', "'xxxx'", 'if', 't=', "'xx'", 'else', 't.replace', ["'a'", ',', "''"], '.replace', ["'b'", ',', "''"], ',', '[', "'col_name1'", '],', "'col_name'", ',', "'string'"]]
  [0]:
    ['lambda', 'x:', "'xxxx'", 'if', 't=', "'xx'", 'else', 't.replace', ["'a'", ',', "''"], '.replace', ["'b'", ',', "''"], ',', '[', "'col_name1'", '],', "'col_name'", ',', "'string'"]
    [0]:
      lambda
    [1]:
      x:
    [2]:
      'xxxx'
    ... every word in the args broken out separately
    [16]:
      ,
    [17]:
      'string'
- name: 'extend'


restrict(lambda x:x !=0, ['col'])
['restrict', ['lambda', 'x:x', '!=0,', '[', "'col'", ']']]
- args: [['lambda', 'x:x', '!=0,', '[', "'col'", ']']]
  [0]:
    ['lambda', 'x:x', '!=0,', '[', "'col'", ']']
- name: 'restrict'
```

If you just want the args list as a string, then you can wrap in pyparsing's `originalTextFor`. Change `arg_list` to:

```
arg_list = pp.originalTextFor(pp.nestedExpr())
```

Now rerunning the tests gives:

```
extend(lambda x: 'xxxx' if t='xx' else t.replace('a','').replace('b',''), ['col_name1'], 'col_name', 'string')
['extend', "(lambda x: 'xxxx' if t='xx' else t.replace('a','').replace('b',''), ['col_name1'], 'col_name', 'string')"]
- args: "(lambda x: 'xxxx' if t='xx' else t.replace('a','').replace('b',''), ['col_name1'], 'col_name', 'string')"
- name: 'extend'


restrict(lambda x:x !=0, ['col'])
['restrict', "(lambda x:x !=0, ['col'])"]
- args: "(lambda x:x !=0, ['col'])"
- name: 'restrict'
```

If you want to remove the opening and closing ()'s, and parse out the delimiting commas, that is an exercise left for the reader/OP. (If this is the case, you may want to go back to the first version, and work with the parsed-out bits of the arg list instead of the all-one-string version.)

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for answering the question. My expectation from the parser is to get the function name(which is fairly easy) and to get the argument list. For example, in the first function :extend(lambda x: 'xxxx' if t='xx' else t.replace('a','').replace('b',''), ['col_name1'], 'col_name', 'string') the expected result is [extend, ["lambda x: 'xxxx' if t='xx' else t.replace('a','').replace('b',''), ['col_name1'], ", ['col_name1'], 'col_name', 'string']. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: As I said, I leave that as an exercise for you to work through.

Comment: haha ok, didn't know that you were referring to it. thanks for your prompt response though

Comment: One follow up question. in function restrict(lambda x:x != 0,[col]), if there is no space between first and second arguments then it seems the parsing doesn't work as intended. how can we ignore the space?

Comment: This is because `nestedExpr` is little more than a detector of nesting opening and closing strings, in this case, '(' and ')'. The content with the parens is not really parsed, so much as just broken up at spaces. For you to detect the arguments, you will need to use `originalTextFor` to get back the original string. At this point you *should* be able to use `ast.literal_eval`, but it seems that this will only work for arg lists that do not include a `lambda`. If you are confident that the source of the text is safe, you can `eval()` the string emitted by `originalTextFor`.

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to implement your own parser for general Python expressions, which will be a very involved task.